# Spaming CakePHP email and how to check mail is read by User

Tags: php, email, cakephp

Using below code in CakePHP i am sending emails to my users.
But why my emails are going in Spam folder and 
Also i want to check that User read the mail or not.
how it could be ?

I have read on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

There they say with "readReceipt" we can receive the receipt of read.

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->emailFormat('both');
$Email->from(array($webAdminData['User']['email'] => $webAdminData['User']['first_name'].' '.$webAdminData['User']['last_name']));
$Email->replyTo(Configure::read('Email.EmailSupport'),Configure::read('SITE_SETTINGS.Name'));
$Email->sender(array($webAdminData['User']['email'] => $webAdminData['User'['first_name'].' '.$webAdminData['User']['last_name']));
$Email->to($this->request->data['Message']['leadEmail']);
$Email->subject($this->request->data['Message']['subject']);
$Email->send($this->request->data['Message']['body']);                          
$this->Session->setFlash('Message has been sent successfully', 'default', 'success');
```

Comment: You can't check mail is read by user or not.

Comment: @Manwal You can in case the receiving mail client supports it (in most cases it requires user confirmation tough). The technical term for this is "Message Disposition Notification", short "MDN".

Comment: Ohhhh good infomartion thanks @ndm

Answer (score 0):

If email is going to Spam folder, the causes will be many.

1. Check the content of your email. Some email client will filter your email and move it to spam if it contains any spam related content.
2. Your email server has been marked as spam server. (this often occurs for shared hosting email provider)